# How to generate a set of random numbers in both Lua and C# that are the same?

Tags: c#, random, lua

I need to generate a set of random numbers from a seed in Lua and then generate the same set of random numbers in c# from the same seed, What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need the same code to generate the same random numbers.  The Lua library is uncomplicated and passes the job to the [C runtime library](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lmathlib.c.html).  That makes it somewhat likely that you'll get the same numbers if you use it as well.  Easy to do with pinvoke:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
...
    public static double LuaRandom() {
        const int RAND_MAX = 0x7fff;
        return (double)(rand() % RAND_MAX) / RAND_MAX;
    }

    public static void LuaRandomSeed(int seed) {
        srand(seed);
    }

    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern int rand();
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern void srand(int seed);
```

Write a little test program in both Lua and C#, be sure to use LuaRandomSeed() and math.randomseed() so they start at the same sequence and compare the first ~25 numbers they spit out.  If you don't get a match then your Lua implementation is using a different C runtime library and you'll have to write your own random number generator.  The simple LCG that Microsoft uses:

```
private static uint seed;

public static int rand() {
    seed = seed * 214013 + 2531011;
    return (int)((seed >> 16) % RAND_MAX);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 random generators that use the same algorithm and parameters.

The .NET framework does not guarantee anything about the generator (ie it could change in a future version). I don't know much about Lua but it probably has a standard generator based on the implementing platform with similar vagaries.

So your most reliable course would be to pick [an algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) and implement it yourself on both platforms. And then all you need is a common seed to generate identical sequences.